# Wordpress - Azure AppService database "rollback"

Tags: database, wordpress, azure, rollback, azure-appservice

I have WordPress set up in the Azure AppService environment. For a while after filling in the content, everything is fine (I see the article on the front end and in the backend), but upon returning (after more than 2 weeks), I see that the content is empty.

This only affects certain parts of the site:

1. all articles in CPT updated at one time
2. one page

Debugging:

- Revisions are empty (the system works properly)
- Database records - the same as shown in the backend, the content is empty
- I don't have access to logs

Additional info:

- Server by Azure App Service. Latest Wordpress and plugins
- Cache system by W3 Total Cache
- Plugins:
- - Advanced Custom Fields PRO
- - All In One WP Security
- - App Service Email
- - Resizable Editor Sidebar
- - Smush
- - W3 Total Cache
- - WP Migrate (Configured to pull the database, not override it)
- - WPO365 | LOGIN

The problem seems as if the database "rolls back" sometimes. WordPress operates, but the content has disappeared twice already.

The life of the database looks like this, where it should be a straight line:
[database-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCY7A.png).

Comment: Do you have App service Configuration related to Wordpress in Environmnet Variables section.

Comment: Check this [Blog](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-rollback-wordpress-plugins-version-control-for-beginners/) once.